# The strong force, gluons, and $m=E/c^{2}$: Is the equal sign replaced by "is"?

Tags: special-relativity, particle-physics, mass-energy

In his book [Quantum Space](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07VDG769F) page 82, Baggott says "In fact, elaborate QCD calculations demonstrate that about 95 percent of the mass of a proton or neutron is derived from the energy of massless gluons that carry the colour force between the quarks....  We see that Einstein's great insight was indeed that $m=E/c^{2}$ the mass of a body is a measure of its energy content, and we conclude that mass is not something that an object has.  Instead, the mass of an object is something that it does."

My question.  In all other cases I have assumed that energy "equals" $mc^2$.  But in the case of gluons and the strong force, are we now at the situation where energy "is" $mc^2$?

Comment: What distinction are you making between "is" and "equals"?

Comment: @probably_someone  4 quarters equals one dollar, but 4 quarters is not one dollar.  Regarding E=mc^2, I have always made the assumption that the mass must go through a conversion in order to become energy.  But the paragraph appears to state otherwise.  The mass is energy.

Comment: I mean, both are true in a certain sense. Mass is a form of energy that can be converted into other forms of energy. For example, nuclear fission converts mass-energy into kinetic and electromagnetic energy, just like a generator converts kinetic energy into electrical energy and a battery charger converts electrical energy into chemical energy.

Comment: @foolishmuse no conversion is needed. Indeed, if a conversion were needed then it is hard to see how energy could be conserved

Answer (score 1):

We are now at a stage where an almost complete particle mathematical theoretical model exists and the various insights of the great physicists that built up the present day model are in appropriate theoretical form.This theory, [the standard model,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model) is based on special relativity and Lorentz transformation.  The $m=E/c^2$ can be used for single massive elementary particles, but the full theory with its vectorial representation of four vectors has to be used in order to model the particle data.

As you can see, photons and gluons and other zero mass particles which may exist cannot be modeled by the primitive expression of relativity. The full [complement of four vectors](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/vec4.html) has to be used where mass is defined as the "length" of the four vector.

> The length of the energy-momentum 4-vector is given by

[image]

> the length of this 4-vector is the rest energy of the particle. The invariance is associated with the fact that the rest mass is the same in any inertial frame of reference.

This length is the invariant mass of a single particle.

In this larger and correct representation zero mass particles have energy which can be four-vectorially added to give the mass of a composite system. The length of the vector sum  is the invariant mass of the composite system.

It is mathematically obvious from vector algebra that the primitive assumption of $m=E/c^2$  is valid only for single particles. A vectorial addition of particles , as with three dimensional length, will give an invariant mass for a complex system, as the proton, that is larger than the sum of the elementary particle masses comprising it.

> that about 95 percent of the mass of a proton or neutron is derived from the energy of massless gluons that carry the color force between the quarks.

The mass in this statement is the invariant mass of the summed four vectors of the composite proton or neutron.

The $m=E/c^2$ is no longer in use in particle physics  as it describes only  a small part of data  and leads to misunderstandings about the definition of mass.

Comment: Thanks for this.  Allow me to read up on four vectors before I come back with questions.

Comment: Really nice answer.

Comment: @anna v   After many hours of study, l think I've figured it out.  The page I found very informative is https://tinyurl.com/y8qvk5oy  1/3 down you can see "if the object is moving, its mass is still m and its energy E is greater than m c2, with the excess due to motion-energy.". As he mentions, amateurs are often not familiar with invariant mass.  So now, because of the movement of the particles, I understand that E>mc^2  This relates directly back to the OP where "the mass of an object is something that it does"