# How did scientists come to know what to do with $E=mc^2$?

Tags: special-relativity, nuclear-physics, mass-energy

When Albert Einstein proposed his famous equation $E=mc^2$ for rest mass he never said anything it's about about breaking the nucleus. Then how did scientists come to know what this mean?

But again mass is not only about the nucleus. There are electrons and protons made up of quarks. Shouldn't that protons and neutrons break apart too, until all became pure energy like photons?

Comment: $E=mc^2$ isn't the full equation.  The full equation is $E^2=\left(mc^2\right)^2+(pc)^2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nuclei are not elementary particles, but they are made up of smaller elements with a lower mass, i.e., protons and neutrons. This is they main reason why they can decay (break down). Electrons are elementary particles, and there is no other particle similar to the electron (technically, a lepton) with a smaller mass, therefore they cannot "break down". However, electron can be converted in photons (as you said, "pure energy") in the process called electron-positron annihilation. Basically, if an electron $e^-$ collides with its antiparticle $e^+$ (positron) the outcome of the collision is the production of photons $\gamma$ as
$$e^-+e^+\to2\gamma$$
So, you cannot break down an electron to get photons, the only way to get photons out of electrons is to collide matter and antimatter. Regarding neutrons, they can actually "break down". There are more than one type of neutron decay, but the most frequent is $$n\to p+e^-+\nu$$ where $n$. The proton decay is a matter of speculations so far. However, all particles can annihilate when they collide with their own antiparticles, producing photons, in a way which is analogous to the electron-positron decay.

Importantly, if you use $E=m c^2$ to calculate the total energy before and after any decay process, the initial and final energies are the same, that is, the energy is conserved.

Comment: Than you and if you could please answer this too .its this discovery made me ask this question. '' phys.org/news/2019-02-physicists-proton-pressure.html ''. so if we were to break the protons apart too then the predicted energy by the equation is way too small isnt it ?

Comment: The mass of the proton is approximately the same of the mass of the neutron. The energy equivalent of the proton mass is large enough to produce decay. However, neutrons decay, but protons seems to be stable. I say "it seems" because the estimated half-life of the proton is 10$^30$ years. Basically, nobody ever saw a proton decay. You can in any case produce photons by proton-antiproton collision. Is this answering your question?

Comment: well explained Thanks

Answer (score 1):

My answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/578040/the-strong-force-gluons-and-m-e-c2-is-the-equal-sign-replaced-by-is/578054#578054) covers the question about the relativistic energy formula.

> shouldnt that photons and neutrons break apart too , until all became pure energy like photons?

The mainstream particle physics model is the [standard model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model), and there axiomatically photons and electrons etc are defined as point elementary particles. It is a quantum field theoretical model and fits the enormous plethora of particle data to date. Quantum mechanics is a probabilistic theory, the only predictions are on probability of measuring a particle at (x,y,z,t).

Still a few theorists among them ['t Hooft](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/11205/g-t-hooft) are studying beyond the standard model deterministic models, but it is difficult to find mathematical models that will embed the standard model (an encapsulation of all data) and at the same time be predictive of differences, they have not succeeded up to now. Once such models come to existence one could study the consequences on the stability of what are now considered elementary point particles.